# How to access child class variable from parent class during runtime?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, scope

I have multiple child classes that extend a parent class.

**Parent Class:**

```
Class ParentClass{

    public void printMessage() {
    Reporter.log("Child Class Name at Runtime = " +this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    Reporter.log("Child Class Variable Value at Runtime = ");
}
```

}

**Child Class A:**

```
    Class ChildA extends ParentClass{
     String customerName = "Adam";
     printMessage();

}
```

**Child Class B:**

```
Class ChildB extends ParentClass{
    String customerName = "Bob";
    printMessage();

    }
```

When I run either of the classes, I want the output to be like below:

If I run ClassA:

```
Child Class Name at Runtime = Class A
Child Class Variable Value at Runtime = Adam
```

Similarly, for other child classes like ClassB, etc.

I do not want to pass the argument of customerName when I call the printMessage() method due to a few reasons (hundreds of message calls).

How can I access the runtime value of the class variable of a child class from a parent class?

I have checked the methods available with this.getClass(), but couldn't find one I could use.

The class is decided at runtime. That's why I use this.getClass().getSimpleName() and it works fine in printing the child class name at runtime.

Comment: and I assume you don't want to use the variable as static, right?

Comment: I am okay with using static variables.

Comment: `getClass().getDeclaredField("customerName").get(this)`

Comment: Can you not define an abstract method though? This seems pretty unsafe

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I would assume declaring `static String customerName = "Bob";` and calling `A.customerName;` would work. You may want to try that, but that may not be the greatest solution you are looking for here.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Can you please add your comment as an answer? I shall accept and mark it as the answer. It worked for me.